# hosts.allow: Not required when using iptables?

Tags: debian, iptables

I am trying to configure the box I am using as a gateway/proxy/firewall to allow IP masquerading and finally switch over from using a proxy. It's a debian squeeze system.

Currently, my hosts.allow file is empty (and hosts.deny says `ALL: PARANOID`), because squid allows requests on the required ports anyway (and also, I can ssh to the box just fine).

Does iptables work the same way, i.e. can the hosts.allow file remain empty when iptables is set up properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hosts.*` files are not required when using iptables. Both have the ability to deny/allow access but work in very different ways.

```
       Network
          |
       IPTables
         /  \  
TCPWrapper  Squid/Daemon
  Daemon
```

Iptables is a kernel base packet filtering framework operating at a layer below tcpwrappers. If you DROP or REJECT something with `iptables` the packet will never reach userspace. It doesn't matter what the program is or how it is written, the packet will never exist from it's point of view.

Programs that use TCPwrappers and it's `hosts.*` functionality run in user space and have to be built with [libwrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libwrap) to make use of the files, or emulate it by reading the hosts files and closing connections they receive from denied clients.

Squid doesn't read the `hosts.deny|allow` files. It has it's own implementation for access control specified with [acl's in `squid.conf`](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl).  In the same way you can configure squids access control on top of iptables, you can use hosts.deny/allow on top of iptables. Those rules only come into play if iptables has let's the traffic through. Not that many programs support tcp_wrappers these days either, `inetd`, the super server, was the main one bit is slowly disappearing.

Comment: `iptables` runs on the host, so even if you DROP or REJECT a packet it has reached the system. It's a somewhat minor detail, but it *is* important sometimes.

Comment: corrected, cheers

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes. TCPwrappers (which is what consults hosts.allow and hosts.deny) is a separate access control method from iptables, using one does not require or impede the use of the other. The only concern will be to ensure required access is allowed through both, if they are both active on the system.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are still able to connect to SSH with an empty *hosts.allow* is probably because **by default tcpwrappers allows all connections** unless you explicitly deny them.

One way to get the opposite (default deny) behaviour is to add the following line to */etc/hosts.deny* (carefull not to shut yourself out!)

```
ALL: ALL
```

Tcpwrappers (hosts.allow and hosts.deny) doesn't work for every network service, like iptables does.

You can often see if a daemon supports tcpwrappers by checking if it is linked against libwrap, like this:

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/sshd | grep libwrap
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f389b5a2000)
```

If there is no output, tcpwrappers is likely not supported by that daemon.

On a final note, I think a very common setup is to only use iptables and leave tcpwrappers unconfigured.

Comment: My `hosts.deny` is a one-liner saying `ALL: PARANOID`. I believe that ssh is yet another service that doesn't look at `hosts.allow|deny`.

Comment: @zebonaut: But paranoid doesn't block everything. It only blocks, quoting `man hosts_access`, *Matches any host whose name does not match its address.*

Comment: As you can see from my `ldd` example, sshd *can* in fact support tcpwrappers.